# Singleton Manager initWithDelegate

Tags: swift, object, delegates, singleton

I have 2 managers. One is child of the other.

**Manager1.h**

```
@protocol LoginDelegate <NSObject>

-(id) loginOK: (id) response;
-(id) loginKO: (id) response;

@end

@protocol LogoutDelegate <NSObject>

-(id) logoutOK: (id) response;
-(id) logoutKO: (id) response;

@end

@interface Manager1 : NSObject

- (id) init __attribute__((unavailable("You have to use Manager2 instead.")));
-(id) login;
-(id) logout;

@end
```

**Manager1.m**

```
@interface Manager1 ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <LoginDelegate> loginDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <LogoutDelegate> logoutDelegate;

@end

@implementation Manager1

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id)aDelegate
{
    self.logoutDelegate = aDelegate;
    self.loginDelegate = aDelegate;

    return self;
}
```

**Manager2.h**

```
@protocol OperationDelegate <NSObject>

-(id) operationOK: (id) response;
-(id) operationKO: (id) response;

@end

@interface Manager2 : Manager1

+ (Manager2 *)sharedInstance;
-(id)init __attribute__((unavailable("You have to use initWithDelegate instead.")));
-(id)initWithDelegate:(id)aDelegate;
-(void)doOperation;

@end
```

**Manager2.m**

```
@interface Manager2 ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <OperationDelegate> operationDelegate;

@end

@implementation Manager2

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id)aDelegate
{
    if (self = [super initWithDelegate : aDelegate])
    {
        self.operationDelegate = aDelegate;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Actually, I can execute my method without any problem. (Swift example):

**ViewController.m**

```
let manager2 = Manager2(delegate: self)
manager2.login()
manager2.logout()
manager2.doOperation()
```

And the response of my delegate:

```
func loginOK(response: id) {

}

func loginKO(response: id) {

}
```

Now, I want a singleton of Manager2. I **tried** in **Manager2.m**:

```
static Manager2 *sharedManager = nil;

+ (Manager2 *) sharedManager
    {
        @synchronized(self)
        {
            if (sharedManager == nil)
                sharedManager = [[self alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
        }
        return sharedManager;
}
```

**ViewController1.m** It works the response.

```
let manager2 = Manager2(delegate: self)
```

**ViewController2.m** Don´t response anything. Delegates are invalids.

```
let manager2 = Manager2.sharedIntance()
```

How can I do this? I have to send my delegate in the sharedInstance? Thank you very much

Comment: `sharedManager` is a ?? , can't see any declaration. Is it a method or a property or an instance variable ?

Comment: I uptated my question

Comment: I´m thinking if it is really necessary. My idea is not to do initWithDelegate many times.

Comment: It should have a static variable holding the singleton, which is missing here...

Comment: :D See your initWithDelegate method in Manager1, self isn't initialized... it should be similar to your initWithDelegate method in Manager2

Comment: I initialize Manager1 delegates with: if (self = [super initWithDelegate : aDelegate]) in Manager2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the **solution:**

```
static Manager2 *sharedInstance = nil;

- (instancetype)init
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = self;
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

+ (Manager2 *)sharedInstanceWithDelegate: (id)aDelegate
{    
    if (aDelegate != nil)
        [sharedInstance setDelegate:aDelegate];

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

A simple init and then, send the delegate when I get the instance.

Answer (score 0):

To be exact, you initialized the self `Manager2`'s instance using `Manager1's initWithDelegate`

```
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id)aDelegate{
    if (self = [super initWithDelegate:aDelegate]){
        self.operationDelegate = aDelegate;
    }
    return self;
}
```

but `Manager1` didn't initialized it, as it should rather be

```
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id)aDelegate{
    if (self = [super init]){
        self.logoutDelegate = aDelegate;
        self.loginDelegate = aDelegate;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help. You´re right, but this doesn´t influence

Comment: try creating singleton using GCD based code using 'dispatch_once', if it helps.... also it should be `initWithDelegate:nil` in `sharedManager`